# Recommendations for search terms - insulate wall between duplex units

Tags: insulation, basement, code-compliance, basement-refinishing

I have one half of a duplex, which is separated by a brick wall (looks like a triple brick?). While refinishing my basement,  I'm trying to determine the insulation requirements in my local building code (Ontario, Canada), but no matter what I punch into google I cant find the right reference.

Can anyone suggest the search term I should be using to find the correct part of my local code?

Thanks!

Comment: Whatever language there may be will be about the fire-rating of said **party wall**, not thermal insulation. If the neighbor is not prone to leaving the house unheated in winter, there should be little temperature variation across the wall, on average.  When that differential shoots up to 900 degrees, it's good if you can leave the house before a fire breaks through...

Comment: Will the space behind the wall be about the same temperature as your space? If so, what do you expect insulation to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### There actually aren't any (at least in the Model Codes)

The reason you're coming up empty handed is because the Code makers, by and large, *have not addressed this* when writing energy conservation codes.  Party (common) walls are generally not considered part of the building thermal envelope, which is actually rather OK, as insulating them poses special challenges.

From the [Building America Solutions Center page on the topic](https://basc.pnnl.gov/code-compliance/air-sealing-and-insulating-common-walls-party-walls-multi-family-buildings-code) (italics in original):

> The model energy codes do not address minimum insulation requirements for common walls because the common wall is not defined as part of the *building thermal envelope*.

If you want to insulate and/or air seal them, you must respect the wall's fire rating and listing when insulating in order to be Code compliant.  You may wish to speak with your AHJ on this, especially considering that you are dealing with an older style of party wall which behaves differently from modern residential party walls.

Answer (score 1):

The article and discussion found in the article referenced by @ThreePhaseEel indicates no code reference specifically to party walls. However, all major codes reference energy compliance for "Dwelling Unit's Walls". I think the article is misleading when it implies there is no energy code requirements for "party walls."

Yes, the code is very specific for fire separation for "party walls" in multi-family structures. (By the way, as of 2014 Code, fire sprinklers are also required for 3 units and more.)

However, all party walls have "sound wall" requirements.  I'm not sure what your party wall's sound transmissions class (STC) is, but I'm sure the brick wall does not meet the required "R value" for walls in a "dwelling unit"...as required by all codes.

We try to "kill two (or three) birds with one stone" and use thermal insulation in a party wall design to meet sound wall requirements and fire wall separation requirements.

So, I'd suggest use the same thermal value in your party wall as your exterior walls to meet the energy requirements for dwelling units.

Comment: The prime concern I'd have with insulating a party wall is that combustible insulation materials (foam, celluosic) could void the fire wall listing/rating depending on the existing construction and means of installation.  Air sealing could also have an impact on this as well...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  I don't think you can get a "fire rating" using combustible insulation. I've never heard of it. Can you?

Comment: Well, ICF walls are often considered to have some degree of fire rating performance AIUI even though the forms will burn off the exposed side after the finish is no longer able to hold...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  Hmmm...my UL Fire Rated Listing Manual doesn't have ICF listed. Are they?

Comment: Interesting -- my understanding could be wrong, at least for first gen (foam sandwich) ICFs.  (There are what I call "second gen" ICF technologies (such as Apex Blocks) that use a foam-aggregate PCC -- these *do* have an official fire rating, at least if the specification sheets are any guide.)

Comment: I did find this, but it doesn't seem to have a UL listing, so I don't think building codes would accept it as "Fire Rated".   https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjohZ_R0eTUAhUH34MKHajRBDcQFggKMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.forms.org%2Findex.cfm%2Ffireresistance&usg=AFQjCNFfyzsRArCm68BcEuKPIVo3tpi5sA

Comment: that's because it's through ICC-ES, not UL -- here's the [eval report](http://apexblock.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/icc-apex.pdf) btw.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I think it is approved, but with a footing, it could be pretty expensive compared to a wood frame wall with one layer of 5/8" Fire Code Type-X gypsum board on each side. It looks like the ICF can give you up to a 3-hour fire wall (which is pretty high) but for non-load bearing walls. Most party walls require just a one-hour fire rated wall, which the wood frame wall with 5/8" Type-X gypsum board meets. For the duplex he's asking about, I think the wood frame wall might work best.

Comment: he's not replacing the wall anyway (he has an existing triple wythe brick party wall and wants to insulate his side of it)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Oh I'm not suggesting to "replace" the wall...but, in order to meet fire separation requirements, which I suspect are none, AND to insulate the wall , I'd use wood framing rather than ICF.